# Selecting a child element of an adjacent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I'm attempting to use .parents to select an element in an adjacent ul so that I can click one to affect the other.

I can select the parent .outside of both ul, starting from the span within .ulB however when I ask it to go back in and select .ulA it doesn't like it.

Any ideas? It is possible to do this using this method or at all? Thanks.

Example code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
  .ancestors * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").parents(".outside > .ulA").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
</script>

</head>

<body class="ancestors">
  <div class="outside" style="width:500px;">

    <ul class="ulA">  
      <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="ulB">
      <li>
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Benya16 No. this is a case where a class is required. he finds it via location+class -  not via id. If this is inside a repeater he's f*ed. No Id's are required for UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no parent of a `span` matching `.outside > .ulA`. You need to find the parent first, *then* find the `.ulA` descendant:

```
$("span").
  parents(".outside").
  find(".ulA").
  css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

```js
  $("span").parents(".outside").find(".ulA").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
```

```css
  .ancestors * {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ancestors">
  <div class="outside" style="width:500px;">

    <ul class="ulA">
      <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="ulB">
      <li>
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parents selector does not exist.

You first need to *find* the parent and *then* search within it.

Also - use `closest`. You don't need `parents`(unless filtering later) , and also it's faster than `parent`.`closest` already returns the first match.

```
$("span").closest(".outside").find(".ulA").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```